# How to extract urls from a table with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, extract

Hello I am trying to extract the urls of all basketball events inside the table from this webpage : https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20200907/

Here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/basketball/20200907/")

url_links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/basketball/')]")))]

print(len(url_links), '\n')

print(url_links, '\n')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The output gives me the urls of the table and others. In my case I just want the 9 urls linked to the 9 basketball events. How to filter these urls ?

Thanks

Comment: You can narrow down your xpath. The urls are in the second `td` of each `tr`. Maybe something like `//td[2]/a[contains(@href, '/basketball/')]`

Comment: Thank you for your return I tried your method now I have 16 urls but in my case I only want the urls of the basketball events. These urls are stocked in the first tbody balise. The others urls come from the calendar at the right of the table. How to only select the elements of ther first tbody ?

Comment: Maybe `//*[@id="table-matches"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[contains(@href, '/basketball/')]` works.